# how to replace single escape char with double using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to replace single escape char \ with double \ using sed
However when I use

```
`echo $regex | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'`
```

it returns 
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
is there a solution for this?

Comment: Add double quotes around "$regex".

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

  > "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes><br>
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments><br>
<http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words><br>

Comment: It [seems to work](https://ideone.com/bGopWp)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help, `echo "$regex_b" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'` 
still return the same:
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command

Comment: You don't have to use `/` as the `sed` delimiter. `sed 's@/@//@g'` should do the trick.

Comment: tried with it too but didn't work out, seems like sed doesn't catch delimiters when I put these escapes

Comment: use $() instead of `` worked, thanks for answers!

Comment: With backticks, you have to escape **all** the backslashes: ``echo "`echo "$regex" | sed 's/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g'`"`` -- a compelling reason to use `$(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the backticks are making the escape character get evaluated again before being passed to `sed`. To get around that, double up how often they get escaped.

```
`echo $regex | sed 's/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g'`
```

Your original rendition would have worked fine if you had not used backticks.

```
echo $regex | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
```

And this would have worked fine if you had encapsulated it within `$()` instead of backticks (as described in another answer).

As noted in comments, if this is part of a script where you are building a pattern to be used elsewhere, there is likely a weakness in your approach if you need this kind of manipulation.

Comment: The backticks are either an artifact of the question or a problem in and of themselves. Nothing about the name `regex` suggests that the result of the substitution is a command to execute.

Comment: @chepner: You are saying the OP should clarify why backticks are involved at all. I agree.

Comment: I need to put this to variable so that's why I use ``, but your answer or using $() is solution here

Comment: @xenofu So your command is actually something like ``foo=`echo $regex | ...` ``?

Answer (score 0):

I took the commands in the question and ran like so in `BASH`:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='This\is a \ test'
echo $regex
echo $regex | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'

results=$(echo $regex | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')
echo $results
```

This gives me the expected result of `\\` for every found backslash. In the last two lines, I stored the output into a variable called `$results`, which appears to be what was attempted in the question with the backticks.

Comment: ok here is solution, if I use $() instead of `` it works, Thank you for answer!